# InfoPath 2007 code Behind Deployment

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, infopath-2007

I have designed a form which has code behind attached to IT. I have to deploy the form with code behind in the Server.

I have uploaded the .xsn file to central administartion and Activated it on the web application.

I need to upgrade the coding and update the functionality of the Same.

could anybody point me in right direction for deploying and Upgrading the Infopath forms 2007 with Code Behind.

Thank you
Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade your form as a result of code/functionality change, repeat the whole process of deployment you did earlier:

1. Upload the form to Server from Designer. (you specify a template save location for admins to pick-up)
2. Upload the template on server from, central admin.
3. Check 'Upgrade the form template if it already exists'.
4. Select either for sessions to complete or terminate, depending on your scenario.

Note: Upgrade process doesn't affect activation status of the template.

Comment: How do I link .xsn to the Code behind file. Could you guide me ? I am not fully aware of deployment Process

Comment: 1. Open the form in designer and 2. Open FORM OPTIONS. On your left side will be a category list, select PROGRAMMING. After this Select Programming language from "Form template code language" dropdown - VB or C#. Then you can select controls on your form and go to their event handlers (Code editor autimatically opens if not already open) or you can press Alt + Shift + F12.